# a list for px.histogram

Tags: python, plotly, histogram

I want to make several histograms by using a list.

The code for one graph works perfectly:

```
fig = px.histogram(gym, x='gender', y='Phone', color='Churn', barmode='relative', template='simple_white')`
```

But my list for histograms is not working:

```
for column in ['gender', 'Near_Location', 'Partner', 'Promo_friends', 'Contract_period']:
    plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
    fig = px.histogram(gym, x=gym[column], y='Phone', color='Churn', barmode='relative', template='simple_white',)
    plt.title(column)
    plt.show(fig)
```

I can't understand where's the problem?

Comment: I can't see a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Put yourself in the shoes of a SO contributor, by pasting in your example and trying to run it without additional context.

Answer (score 0):

The `x` parameter in `px.histogram` should be the column name for the gym dataframe, not the column of the dataframe itself.

The following should work:

```
for column in ['gender', 'Near_Location', 'Partner', 'Promo_friends', 'Contract_period']:
    plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
    fig = px.histogram(gym, x=column, y='Phone', color='Churn', barmode='relative', template='simple_white',)
    plt.title(column)
    plt.show(fig)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone! I've managed to find a working code:

```
for column in ['gender', 'Near_Location', 'Partner', 'Promo_friends', 'Phone', 'Contract_period', 'Group_visits']:
    fig = px.histogram(gym, x=column, y='Phone', color='Churn', barmode='relative', template='simple_white',title = column)
    fig.show()
```

Comment: Instead of repeating an answer someone else has given, instead upvote their answer and optionally comment on their answer to give thanks:)